# Chrome web request api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using the chrome web request api. But the web request API presents an abstraction of the network stack, and does not present headers for authorization, cache control ect. Is it possible for me to get the all the request headers. I am aware that i can use onSendHeader to view the traffic but i want to make a blocking call. I am trying to use my plugin to add cookies to all of the http request headers. There are some requests which bypass the plugin. These request appear in the network tab of the developer console in chrome but do not appear in my plugin.

```
function setup()
{
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
        requestMonitor.insertHeaders,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve? There is no single satisfying answer to the question "how to get all request headers in a blocking way".

Comment: I am trying to add a cookie to the request headers, but there are some requests that i get on the network tab in the developer console in chrome , but not in my javascript plugin. I need to get all of the requests to go through my plugin.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a small yet complete sample of your code plus steps yo reproduce your observation? And while we are at it, edit the title such that it is closer to your actual question.